# Can't fund file location

Tags: java, javax.sound.sampled

I am trying to play the .wav file but for some reason, I am always getting the error of can't find the error. Below is my code:

```
package Program;

public class YuanVideoGameStore {

    //VARIABLES:
    static final String BACKGRUONDMUSIC = "/YuanVideoGameStore/src/reasources/b2.wav";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PlayMusic play = new PlayMusic();
        play.BackGroundSound(BACKGRUONDMUSIC);

    }

}

    package Program;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem;
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.DataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.LineUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.sampled.Mixer;
import javax.sound.sampled.UnsupportedAudioFileException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class PlayMusic {

    static Clip clip;

    void BackGroundSound(String musicLocation) {

        try {
            File musicPath = new File(musicLocation);

            if(musicPath.exists()) {
                AudioInputStream audioInput = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(musicPath);

                clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
                clip.open(audioInput);
                clip.start();
                clip.loop(Clip.LOOP_CONTINUOUSLY);

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please don't press the button");
            }else {System.out.print("Cannot find file!");}
        }catch(Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

I had to call on the file using a related path because this program is going to be handed to my teacher. And I have already tried many times but the music file is still not being played. Please help.

[image]

Comment: You are **not** using a  relative path. Also where are yours class files located?

Comment: I have tried using a relative path but it didn't work so I tried the direct path just to see if the program work. In terms of a class file, I am not so sure where it is. But my two classes are in the two .java files. thank you.

Comment: JVM executes compiled classes. Relative path should be based on location of `.class` files.

Comment: oh ok thank you, problem solved : )